# Slow getimagesize

Tags: php, performance, getimagesize

I need to show multiple posts on my website. These posts are combined of internal and external posts. The external posts are periodically imported and saved in my DB using a cronjob.

Before showing the posts I extract the text from all HTML. In addition I try to locate the first image contained in the post, continuing until I find an image which height & width meets my requirements. (I only show a small version of the text, and one picture from the post as a teaser)

For the purpose of finding the most suitable picture, I use getimagesize, but unfortunately this often creates PHP Execution time of several seconds!

How can I speed up my function below? I'm desperate for tips and good tweaking methods!!

Thanks in advance

```
//extract text without tags from blog post
$content = str_get_html("".$post_text."")->plaintext;

$max_width = 475;
$picture_id = 0;

//fetch images from blog post
foreach($html->find('img') as $e) {

//get picture attributes
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize((is_absolute_url($e->src) ? $e->src : $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$e->src));

//adjust image width & height, so it's the size of the page
$new_width = $max_width;
$new_height = $new_width / $width * $height;

//find percentage of current width versus max width
$percentage = ($width / $max_width) * 100;

    //select picture for display and resizing if the picture is large enough (we don't want to stretch it too much)
    if($percentage >= 60) {

        $e->width = $new_width;
        $e->height = $new_height;

        $picture = array('src' => $e->src, 'width' => $e->width, 'height' => $e->height);

        //stop after first picture is found :: we only need one per post
        if (++$picture_id == 1) break;

    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are querying the image through HTTP. That's probably your problem right there. Not sure whether it is possible to speed that up in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reason:** It is a very well known issue that `getimagesize` works slow on remote files.

**Solution:** It is advised to store the files on your local server (temporarily) and then do `getimagesize` on it.

Comment: Also, include the image scraping process to your cron job.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a url as a parameter to getimagesize, it gets the image through HTTP, what is a slow process.

You should get its size only the first time and save it in a database for the future.